# How to get CCSequence to check if TouchEnded = True

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

I have a Player sprite that moves using finger swipes (ccTouchBegan to ccTouchMoved). I would like to have my action stopped once TouchEnded but I don't want it to end the action half way through. So I'm thinking I'd need my onCallFunc to check if the touch was ended and if so have it exicute stopAllActions. Any ideas on how I can do this?

```
-(void) onCallFunc
{
    // Check if TouchEnded = True if so execute [Player stopAllActions];
    CCLOG(@"End of Action... Repeat");
}
```

-(void) ccTouchMoved:

```
//Move Top
        if (firstTouch.y < lastTouch.y && swipeLength > 150 && xdistance < 150 && xdistance > -150) {        
            CCMoveTo* move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.2  position:ccp(0,1)];
            CCDelayTime* delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:1];
            CCCallFunc* func = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onCallFunc)];
            CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions: move, delay, func, nil];
            CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequence];
            [Player runAction:repeat];
            NSLog(@"my top distance = %f", xdistance);
        }
        if (firstTouch.y < lastTouch.y && swipeLength > 151 && xdistance < 151 && xdistance > -151) {
            NSLog(@"my top distance = %f", xdistance);
        }

    }
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I am trying to simulate the movements made in such games like Pokemon and Zelda by having the player move tile by tile using touch events.

**Update:** After comments to create BOOL flag
I am quite new at using Objective-C but here is me trying to use a BOOL flag. I'm getting an unused variable warning for each section.

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL endBOOL = YES;
    NSLog(@"Stop Actions");
}

-(void) onCallFunc
{
    if(endBOOL == YES){
        [Player stopAllActions];
    }
    // Check if TouchEnded = True if so execute [Player stopAllActions];
    CCLOG(@"End of Action... Repeat");
}
```

Comment: add a bool flag and set it in the touch end and then check it onCallFunc. i dont like to much the design choise with the repeat forever, but i dont get exactly what you trying to achieve.

Comment: I have added 'What I'm trying to achieve:'

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an unused variable warning because you are creating a BOOL flag and then never using it. In your code:

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    BOOL endBOOL = YES;
    NSLog(@"Stop Actions");
}
```

You create the BOOL flag endBOOL inside ccTouchesEnded and once that method is completed the BOOL is no longer kept in memory. To achieve what you want this to do you will need to create an instance variable.

Inside your .h add this

```
// Inside .h
BOOL endBOOL;
```

Then change your code to

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    endBOOL = YES;
    NSLog(@"Stop Actions");
}
```

That way endBOOL is retained and you can use it in your if statement. Also note that the (endBOOL == YES) is not needed. You can simply use this:

```
-(void) onCallFunc
{
    if(endBOOL){
        [Player stopAllActions];
    }
    // Check if TouchEnded = True if so execute [Player stopAllActions];
    CCLOG(@"End of Action... Repeat");
}
```